# Multiple Handlers are conflicting with each other in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, handle

I'm trying to implement some type of function call in `Handler` in order to get function call multiple times. For this purpose I'm using `Alarm Manager` to start Handler. And I successfully did it.

The problem is that when AlarmManager repeats itself after a specific time a new Handle also be created again and the previous one was still here.

I want only one single handler which is being created and called no matter how many times AlarmManger repeat itself.

> Here's my AlarmManger

```
AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),1000*1,  pi);
```

> Here's my class where am I calling Handler

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements VolleyJsonRespondsListener {

 final int delay = 10000; //milliseconds
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable;

@Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("timeOut", "@"+CommonFunctions.getTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));

runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //do something
                Log.e("timeInside", "@"+CommonFunctions.getTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
}
```

In Logcat you can see that there are multiple handlers are conflicting their values with each other. I implemented system time in log and showing it in Logcat.

> Locat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to create thread and looper for that process see this code

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final int delay = 10000;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                //do something
                 handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            });
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because during different instance creation of the `Broadcast`. It's handled by system with pending intent, so all you need it's just annotate Handler, as static object. This will ensure that only one handler created. Please note, this handler will bound to the main thread, because it will use current `Looper`.

```
static final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Comment: @IrfanAkram Otherwise you question just wrong. You try to create long living single instance of object, for this purpose you must use services. For ex. Create and start `Service` on `Broadcast`, with your single instance of `Handler`.